# How to render a dynamic controls in Xamarin xaml

Tags: ios, xamarin

I would like some help as I am new to Xamarin, I'm trying to create a simple Questionair Application, where every question have a corresponding answers value and control type stored in the database.

```
Public class Question
{
   public Guid Id { get; set; }
   public string description { get; set; }
   public List<Answer> Answers { get; set; }
}

Public class Answer
{
   public Guid Id { get; set; }
   public Guid QuestionId { get; set; }
   // This could be radio button, dropdown, calendar picker, textbook, slider
   public string ControlType { get; set; }
   public string answerValue { get; set; }
}
```

So far I was able to get all the answers for every question, however, I'm stuck on how am I able to render this controls in xaml. Hope you could help me guys.

Thank you

Comment: Get a piece of paper and a pencil.  Draw what you want your UI to look like.  Then figure out how to build that in XAML.  And why does `Answer` have the control associated with it?  Shouldn't that be linked to `Question`?

Comment: Hi Jason,

Yeah I guess, it should be better if I put the ControlType in Question Model instead. So are you saying I create all the controls in xaml already? But this set of question might change for every templates, being that said template 1 might have 5 questions, template 2 might have 10 question and so on.

Comment: No, I'm saying you need to have an idea what you expect the UI to look like before you try to build it.  It doesn't have to be done in XAML.  As written your question is incredibly broad an unlikely to be answered.  Pick the most common type of question/answer pattern and figure out how to build that.  Then expand to handle the next kind of question, etc

Comment: As previously mentioned how the UI is expected to look and depending on the level of experience the implementation could change. If there are multiple steps with a dynamic amount of questions per step it may be easier to generate all the controls directly in the .cs file and then just replace/add them to the page on step progression. However, if xaml is preferred the question page could be a ListView/Collection with a DataTemplateSelector and a DataTemplate for each question that chooses the template based it's ControlType.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you want to display all the questions and answers on one interface, you can create a wrapper class with all the properties of the question and answer. Then use ListView or CollectionView to display all the information.
2. If you don't want to display on the same interface, you can display all the questions on the main interface by using ListView or CollectionView. When you click on the question, a pop-up interface (Rg.Plugins.Popup is relatively simple) will appear. There is all the answer information.